# Why can I measure the right voltage value between the high voltage battery positive terminal and chassis ground if they are in different circuits?

Tags: high-voltage

I have a electric vehicle which has some issues.

I measured the voltage between the high voltage battery positive terminal and chassis ground.  I reads 400v - exactly the nominal voltage of HV-BATT. Is that wrong or normal?

If the high voltage battery has different circuit from the low voltage (chassis,) how is it even possible that I can measure the right voltage between the two isolated circuits?

Comment: Are they actually isolated (i.e. floating relative to one another)? Or are they just separate circuits that interface with each other through isolators but both have ground connections to the chassis? There is a difference. What is your reasoning for saying they are isolated?

Comment: I would not expect the HV battery and any LV circuits to be truly isolated, I would expect them to be sharing a chassis connection. Even if they weren't, I would expect considerable leakage between their grounds, which would be enough to convince a DMM. What makes you think they are isolated?

Comment: For strict EMI environments like cars, leaving anything big floating is a big no-no, so basically everything is (at least RF-)bonded to chassis ground. It is very likely that there is indeed a dead short between your battery negative and the chassis.

Answer (score 2):

Although the high-voltage battery and all the high-voltage equipment (inverter, motor etc) are isolated from the chassis for safety reasons, there is an intentional high-value resistor between the battery and chassis.

That resistor would conduct enough to operate the meter.

The value of the resistor is such that there is not enough current to cause a dangerous electrical shock if a human touches any of the high-voltage circuitry.

The resistor values are low enough that that there will be a well-defined voltage present that can be measured by sensing circuitry to detect if there is excessive leakage to ground.

If there is excessive leakage there should be a warning on the dashboard and the high-voltage contactor will be disabled and so prevent the car from operating as it is potentially unsafe.

I'm surprised that you measure 400V - there are usually two resistors so the chassis would be at the mid-point of the battery (ie 200V) to allow any leakage to be detected. Measuring 400V would usually mean that there is a fault on the negative side of the battery to chassis.

You need to give more information in the question, what type of car, whether there are any warnings etc.